# $X,Y$ are independent and $f(X,Y)$ and $Y$ are independent. Does there exists a $g$ s.t. $f(X,Y)=g(X)$ a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $(E,\mathcal{E}),(F,\mathcal{F})$ and $(G,\mathcal{G})$ be measure spaces and $f:E\times F\rightarrow G$ a measurable function.

$X,Y$ are independent RV with values in $E$ and $F$. In my situation $f(X,Y)$ and $Y$ are independent.

Does there exists a measurable function $f':E\rightarrow G$ s.t. $f'(X)=f(X,Y)$ almost surely?

My measure theoretic knowledge is not very strong...if the statespaces need to have some regularity conditions, that would be okay, I'm sure my spaces are nice enough. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general, if I understood correctly your question. Take $E=F=\{0,1\}$, and $X,Y$ be independent Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{2})$ random variables.

Take $f(x,y) = x+y\! \mod 2$. Then $f(X,Y)$ and $Y$ are independent, and no function $f^\prime(X)$ of $X$ only can be a.s. equal to $f(X,Y)$ (which is a uniform r.v. on $\{0,1\}$ independent of $X$).